# Return ACF Number Fields Formatted with Spaces instead of commas

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have this code that helps me to add the comma between thousands but I need just a space instead of commas, how can I do this? I'm new to ACF and PHP as well, so just can't figure out how to do this, help me, please :(
Should be something like this 20 000 instead of this 20,000

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/type=number', 'fix_number', 20, 3);
function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) {
  $value = number_format($value);
  return $value;
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php clearly shows you that the decimal separator and the thousands separator characters can be explicitly specified.

Comment: So should I just add this code? 
number_format(
    float $num,
    int $decimals = 0,
    ?string $decimal_separator = ".",
    ?string $thousands_separator = " "
): string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone needs this

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/type=number', 'fix_number', 20, 3);
function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) {
  $value = number_format($value, 0, ',', ' ');
  return $value;
}
```